# How to insert formula to cell in column with corresponding rownumber?

Tags: google-apps-script

In a sheet called "WHATMONTH" I need to automatically add a formula via. script to range column G2:G, example

=month(A2)

But adding this to he entire sheet in all rows of column G would still give me A2 / month(A2), that should instead be the corresponding row number, and not 2 in all rows.

Here I am just guessing: =month(A%[rownumber]), something like that.

Is this possible?

Comment: why not enter an ArrayFormula ```=ArrayFormula(MONTH($A$2:$A))``` in cell ```A2```? You don't really need a formula in every row to get it working.

Comment: Because I work in 10th of thousands of rows with same variable needs in about 10 columns. Manually adding that is not an option anymore, since the sheet recently have expanded drastically with data and still is.

Comment: But if =ArrayFormula(MONTH($A$2:$A)) could be added with a script - fixed - to G2, then your idea would work, in fact.

Comment: When new data is added from the top of the sheet, it would push the formula down, and fail, if not scripted to be forced into G2

Comment: Sounds like the main problem is that the rows will be pushed down when new data is entered, if that is the case, change the formula to ```=MONTH(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()))``` instead.

Comment: You can than use appscript to placedown the same formula in each cell of the column you want, and the output of the formula will be dynamic to row number.

Comment: @Ping, yes that is exactly the problem. What I need is the script which can insert the formula to a specific cell, and the output of the formula will be dynamic to row number. That script would work.

Comment: use the ```.setFormula()``` method to apply formula to your spreadsheet
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by @Ping. Final working code:

```js
function Setdefault() {
  const setFormula = (sheetName,range,formula) => {
    SpreadsheetApp
      .getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getSheetByName(sheetName)
      .getRange(range)
      .setFormula(formula);
  }
  setFormula('FILTERS','$A$2:$A','=CONCATENATE(\"from:(\",(B2), \") subject:\",(C2),\" older_than:\",(D2),\"d\")');
  setFormula('FILTERS','$D$2:$D','0');
}
```

Comment: If it was solved by @Ping, then you should mark Ping's answer as accepted, not your own.

Answer (score 2):

For short, this is how you can set the formula `=ArrayFormula(MONTH($A$2:$A))` into cell `G2` with appscript according to your request:

```js
// But if =ArrayFormula(MONTH($A$2:$A)) could be added with a script - fixed - to G2, then your idea would work, in fact.

const SheetName = 'Your Sheet Name';
const Range = 'G2';
const Formula = '=ArrayFormula(MONTH($A$2:$A))';

function setFormula(){
  SpreadsheetApp // this call the Spreadsheet related functions.
    .getActiveSpreadsheet() // get spreadsheet_object of the active spreadsheet.
    .getSheetByName(SheetName) // get sheet_object of the sheet from the spreadsheet you are working with by sheet name.
    .getRange(Range) // get range_object of the range from the sheet you are working with.
    .setFormula(Formula); // set a formula into the traget range.
}
```

In case you need to have more than one `Formula` to set, you will have to change the scope of the variables:

```js
function run() {
  const setFormula = (sheetName,range,formula) => {
    SpreadsheetApp
      .getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getSheetByName(sheetName)
      .getRange(range)
      .setFormula(formula);
  }
  
  setFormula("your sheet name 1","range 1","formula 1");
  setFormula("your sheet name 2","range 2","formula 2");
  setFormula("your sheet name 3","range 3","formula 3");
}
```

this format allows you to edit as many sheets, as many cell, with as many formulas as you want to.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same with: 

`=CONCATENATE("from:(",(B2), ") subject:",(C2)," older_than:",(D2),"d")`

I tried: 
`const Formula = '=CONCATENATE("from:(",("$B$2:$B"), ") subject:",("$C$2:$C")," older_than:",("$D$2:$D"),"d")'; `

But that was not working.

Comment: how does your code looks like now? if you let me guess... are you having 2 variables ```Formula``` in the same block of script which makes apps-scripts yelling at you for ```SyntaxError: Identifier 'Formula' has already been declared```?

Comment: you may want to put the ```SheetName```, ```Range```, ```Formula``` variable declarer inside each function to limit their scope, they are now ```global variable``` in my sample.